# Interpretation of Expected value of Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory, probability-distributions

When the sample space in question, is inherently quantifiable and the outcomes have quantifiable relations to each other the expected value is easy to understand, such as the expected value of 3.5 for a die. But what if I have a bag of marbles, 3 red 2 green and 1 blue and I assign the values 1 to red, 2 to green and 3 to blue. The expected value of this would be

$$\sum_{i=1}^3 i\frac{(4-i)}{6}=\frac{5}{3}$$

But what does this mean? And also because the numbering was arbitrary the answer could change depending on the number assignment chosen to each outcome so why is one answer better than another?

Does this have to do with interpretation separately from the pure math?

Answer (score 2):

You're right the answer depends on the values you assign, so if those were just arbitrary values then there's probably not much meaning to it. Maybe those values are prices at which you can sell the marbles. Then your answer gives you the expected amount you earn from picking a marble and selling it.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning values.  You could really assign any values you wanted.  The expected value is a weighted mean, so you multiply the value of an outcome by its probability and then sum over all outcomes as well.  Depending on your assignment of value, your expected value will be different...

Comment: so the answer is the math works regardless of the interpretation? The interpretation is a "higher level" of the actual statistics?

Comment: The interpretation of expected value will never change...it's the weighted average.  What can be changed is the values assigned.  So yes, the math works, interpretation is dependent on values.

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? Math is just a language for studying properties of logical systems. That expected value is a thing you can write down, that makes logical sense in the mathematical language. That doesn't mean it makes sense semantically in the problem you're using math to study.

Comment: Works was a poor wording I mean that the expected value is an element of the formal language as opposed to having semantic meaning

Comment: Then yes, that's exactly right.